# How to communicate from Fragment to ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I currently have an interface that's implemented in the **MainActivity** that allows communication with the **NumberFragment**. The *onCountClicked* is the method in **NumberFragment** receiving the id of the item click.

**Question**

How can I send the *onCountClicked* position to the **NumberFragmentViewModel** every time an item is clicked?

Note: Using databinding & recycleview

**Main Activity**

```
  val newFragment = NumberFragment()
                 val args = Bundle()
                 args.putInt(NumberFragment().onCountClicked(data).toString(),data.toInt())

                newFragment.arguments = args
```

**Number Fragment**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
 val sleepTrackerViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(
                    this, viewModelFactory).get(NumberViewModel::class.java)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

    binding.sleepTrackerViewModel = sleepTrackerViewModel

    //Observes for any changes on database and updates the UI
    sleepTrackerViewModel.dbCount.observe(this, Observer {dbCount ->
        dbView.text = dbCount.number.toString()
    })
    return binding.root
}

   fun onCountClicked(position: Long) {
        Log.i("NumberF" , "------------->" + position)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply create a method in the viewModel that receives that position and updates the value of the live data. I would do it like this:

```
private val _idItemClicked = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val idItemClicked: LiveData<Int> = _idItemClicked

fun setIdItemClicked(id: Int) {
   _idItemClicked.value = id
}
```

Now you call the function **setIdItemClicked** to set a new value.

Comment: Thanks! So once I receive this on the viewModel. How can I transform the live data to an integer? I need to specify the DAO which item ID to get.

Comment: I don't know how you're whole view model looks, but you don't necessarily need to make _idItemClicked of typed MutableLiveData<Int>. If you don't want to set an observer to it, just make it of type Int, delete the idItemClicked variable and in the function just write a _idItemClicked = id.

Comment: I tried doing this as a lateinit variable but would get "has not been initialized". If I initialize the variable as 0, the variable is never changed on click. I'm not sure on what to do.

Comment: I don't know how to help you entirely, because I don't know much of the logic that takes place in your view model. Maybe you should edit your first post and paste some code there. But you can also make the _idItemClicked of type Int? and initialized with null. Then, every time you use it, you should check if it's null or not. If it's null, you should use it. If you declared it as lateinit, then you should also check if it's initialized before using it. Do it with if(!::_idItemClicked.isInitialized)

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a way to do it using SharedViewModel. I will post my solution here.